# jquery hide form field

Tags: jquery

My current code (confirmation message) shows a success message which will then fade out:

```
    echo "<script>$(\".submessage\").hide(\"slow\").fadeIn(\"slow\").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).fadeOut(\"slow\"); $(':input').clearForm() </script>";
```

I would like to achieve that also the input field fades out together with the success message - some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Jasper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this

```
echo "<script>$(\".submessage\")
    .hide(\"slow\").fadeIn(\"slow\")
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000)
    .fadeOut(\"slow\"); $(':input').clearForm(); 
    $(\"#nameOfInput\").fadeOut(\"slow\"); </script>";
```

Comment: Outstanding, it worked ! Thanks for the quick reply and for your help